# State Compression - Where data is stored?

Tags: compression, state, account-compression

My team and I have a doubt where we need some clarification. In the context of state compression:

Is the data stored off-chain or somewhere else within the Solana ecosystem? Where the actual data is getting stored?

Thanks.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** from this [Helius blog post](https://www.helius.dev/blog/solana-nft-compression):

> NFT compression lets developers & creators store the bulk of NFT data
> on the ledger (which is much cheaper than on-chain storage) while
> storing the digital fingerprint of that data on the Solana blockchain
> in the form of a Merkle Tree. If the indexer data is tampered with in
> any way, the digital fingerprint of this data won’t match the
> fingerprint on-chain — thereby guaranteeing data integrity

Whether a ledger is considered on-chain or off-chain is a matter of discussion but Solana founder claims it's on-chain. Two interesting discussions on twitter can be found [here](https://twitter.com/0xMert_/status/1638571693202366464) and [here](https://twitter.com/aeyakovenko/status/1638595516249575424).

Comment: Thanks. The doubts are clarified.